# Volume using Monte Carlo Method

Tags: numerical-methods, volume, monte-carlo

I want to find the volume above $xy$-plane and below the surface given by equation $z = x^2 +2y^2$ for $(x,y) \in [0,1] \times [0,1]$ using Monte Carlo method.

Can anybody help me please? Can you please share related questions so that I can have an idea of how to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know what the Monte Carlo method is?

Comment: Yes I know the basics and pretty comfortable with solving single integrals, value of pi etc ( basic stuff ). Now, its double integral and I am not sure how to solve these type of questions.

Comment: The Monte Carlo method usually refers to a numerical (probabilistic) approach. Here, you could get an approximate solution by using the so called hit-or-miss Monte Carlo method. It doesn't involve integrals - it sounds like you want the exact solution, no?

Comment: Throw random points in the cube $[0,1]\times[0,1]\times[0,3]$, the volume of the regions you're looking for is calculated as the volume of this cube times the number of points within the region, divided by the total number of points you used in the experiment

Comment: @Lovsovs I am looking for related examples that can help me solve it.

Comment: @ caverac Sorry for asking this silly question but why have you included the region [0,3] ? why not just [0,1] x [0,1] ? Like for the case of circle in a cube?

Comment: @user427820 First of all, you want a 3D volume, so simply $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ doesn't work. The $3$ is necessary because your equation for $z$ maxes out at $3$ when $(x,y)=(1,1)$.

Comment: @Lovsovs got it . Can you help me with implementing it using python/Matlab or could share any similar problem?

Comment: In my actual problem, the area is bounded by [0,1] x [0,4] so I need to throw random numbers in the cube [0,1] x [0,4] x [ 0,33] right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you've got the gist of the idea behind the method from the comments above.

Here's the breakdown of the code:

1. Pick a random vector (here a point in 3D) uniformly distributed over a box that *contains* the volume you'd like to sample. It doesn't have to be a snug fit, the box must simply be bigger.
2. If the vector happens to be inside your the region, you'd like to find the volume of, let a counter variable tick one up, e.g. by `k = k+1`.
3. Do this a large number of times, say $N$. Now $$\frac{k}{N}\approx\frac{\text{volume of region}}{\text{volume of box}},$$
   and since the volume of the box is easy to calculate, you can find the desired volume. If $N\rightarrow \infty,$ the approximation will become an equality.

If you're having trouble implementing this in some specific software (like Python or Matlab), please ask over at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to implement it.

Comment: @user427820 Since you are new to the site: If you felt this answered your question, you can "accept" it by clicking the tick next to the answer, giving both you and the answerer a small reputation-boost. Of course, you should choose the best answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

Sample random points $(x_i,y_i)$ uniformly in $[0,1]^2$ and calculate the corresponding $z_i=x_i^2+2y_i^2$ value.

Do this for many sample points, and calculate the average of the $z_i$ values.
This is the average height of your region.
Since the set $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ has area $1$, this average height is equal to the volume of your region.

Comment: What changes would i need if i want to calculate the area for [0,1] x [0,4] ?

Comment: divide by the area (in your example, 4)

Comment: Divide by 4 or multiply by 4?